# Как работает под капотом перенаправление ввода/вывода в linux?

Tags: linux, bash

Pipe принимает вывод от одного процесса и направляет на вход в другой, а перенаправление как работает под капотом? Например echo 'hello' >> test, перенаправление вывода в файл, это понятно, но вывод не на вход же поддается файлу test, как происходит запись в файл?

Comment: а для `'hello' >> test` pipe и не используется, тут с помощью open открывается файл на дописываение с дескриптором == 1

Comment: Я и не говорил что используется pipe, привел пример. То есть в перенаправлении ввода/вывода получается вызывается open file, получаем дескриптор и поток вывода заменяется на этот дескриптор и мы в файле видим вывод команды. понял, спасибо)

Comment: Основа тут [man 2 dup](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html)  / И стоит почитать manpages из раздела SEE ALSO